# Take href of an anchor in a div and apply it to an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with an image and a link in it.

Is it possible that on page load, I can somehow find the href of the link and apply that the anchor tag of the image?

I know this may seem like a strange request, i jsut asking if it can be done, and if so, how?

http://jsfiddle.net/fFgwb/

---

Sorry everyone, I want the image to be wrapped in an anchor tag, witht he same href as the 'continue reading' link

Comment: hmm not quite sure what you mean. You want to make the href of the link the src of the image?

Comment: With jQuery you can get href attribute by $('a').attr('href') , however your question lacks details. Clearify!

Comment: ok, if there are many divs, you can add classes to the elements and it changes the logic too.

Comment: @lukas.pukenis can I downvote your comment??? `$(selector).attr('href')` is literally calling `element.href`. This is why jQuery should have never implemented such methods.

Comment: @rlemon the question has a tag of jQuery. Problem ?

Comment: so jQuery is synonymous with "Add un-needed overhead"? Get you're head on straight. These are bad uses for jQuery, and should be killed before new users adopt them. not the same property, but the [proof is in the perf](http://jsperf.com/stop-using-jquery-for-dumb-shit)

Comment: @lukas.pukenis re:tag is jQuery; yet his fiddle is loading mootools and contains no js at all. also, it is tagged javascript as well. so what is your point.

Comment: @rlemon, again the question is tagged both with JS and jQuery. This is SO, not jsFiddle. Stop spreading your wisdom about best practices when the question is not about that :)

Comment: my goodness you really need to learn what this site is about. the user asked for a generic solution. you provided that solution. I commented stating it is not the best solution and why that is so. Stop spreading your poor practices when there is a more sensible/performant solution staring you in the face.

Answer (score 5):

Still making assumptions about positioning of the elements, but the basics are below. Its *very* simple to do this in pure JS without needing to include jQuery.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/fFgwb/14/)**

```
var link = document.querySelectorAll('.card-prod a');
link[0].href = link[1].href;
```

Comment: why not `document.querySelectorAll('.card-prod a')` ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#theDiv").find("a").attr("href", $('img').attr('src'));

});
```

---

updated:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $("#anchor").attr("href", $('#continue').attr('href'));

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fFgwb/5/

---

so, you should add classes like `.divs` to divs and other classes to anchor links:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".divs").each(function(){

        $(this).find("a").hasClass("anchor").attr("href", $(this).find("a").hasClass("continue").attr('href'))

     });

});
```

Comment: The update to this answer should do it. You'll need to give the continue link and anchor ids of continue and anchor respectively and this'll do it.

Comment: Thanks @JamieHartnoll the only thing is there is going to be multiple divs, all with different links in so the anchors wouldnt work...