# Take href of an anchor in a container and apply it to image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of DIV's that all contain a piece of text, an image, and an anchor.

With Javascript/jQuery, is it possible to take the href of the anchor, and wrap the image in anchor tags with that link?

I know this is a strange requet, Ive made a fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/fFgwb/

---

There will be multiple divs so I cant have the same id

Comment: Can you annotate your fiddle so we have some idea of what you're talking about?  It's not clear from your question here.

Comment: Your img should be www., not www, (note the comma).

Comment: Updated my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fFgwb/9/

Comment: why have you duplicated your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215345/take-href-of-an-anchor-in-a-div-and-apply-it-to-an-image

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way

```
var src = $("#imgid").attr("src"); //take out the src
$("#imgid").wrap($('<a href="'+src+'" />'); //wrap around it with the anchor
```

Your usage, can be something like

```
$("img", $("#divid")).each(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr("src"); //take out the src
    $(this).wrap($('<a href="'+src+'" />')); //wrap around it with the anchor

});
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/fFgwb/13/) with this implementation on your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('img').each(function(){
    $(this).wrap('<a href="'+$(this).attr('src')+'"/>');
});
```

Just narrow that `img` selector, maybe with a class.

Answer (score 0):

If i got what you want correctly, you can do it with something like:

```
$('a').attr('href', function() {
    return $(this).find('img').attr('src');
});​
```

As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/fFgwb/12/).

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
$('.card-prod').each(function () {
    var that = $(this),
        imgA = that.find('a img').parent(),
        newHref = that.find('a').not(imgA).attr('href');
    imgA.attr('href', newHref);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add classes like .divs to divs and other classes to anchor links:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".divs").each(function(){

    $(this).find("a").hasClass("anchor").attr("href", $(this).find("a").hasClass("continue").attr('href'))

});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's wrap it up:

- you'll have several cards
- each card contains two anchors
- the first anchor should get the same href-value as the second anchor

Translated to jQuery:

```
$(".card-prod").each(function(){
    var anchors = $(this).find("a");
    anchors.eq(0).prop("href", anchors.eq(1).prop("href"));
});
```