# jQuery - Get link, apply to other element and hide original

Tags: jquery, css, href

I have the code below. I have several iterations in fact (multiple DIVs with a class of `wpdm-pro`:

```
<div class='wpdm-pro'>
    <div class="metro-block span4 wpdm-metro mm-block-03">
        <div class="caption">
            <h4 class="media-heading" style="padding: 0px;margin:0px">TITLE</h4>
            <br/>
            <div class="btn-group">
              <a class='wpdm-download-link wpdm-download-locked btn btn-success' rel='noindex nofollow' href='http://123.com'>Download</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The question I have is how to grab the URL, apply/wrap the  heading with it and then hide the link/containing div? so it produces something like the below (logically - not physically)

```
<div class='wpdm-pro'>
    <div class="metro-block span4 wpdm-metro mm-block-03">
        <div class="caption">
            <a class='wpdm-download-link wpdm-download-locked btn btn-success' rel='noindex nofollow' href='http://123.com'><h4 class="media-heading" style="padding: 0px;margin:0px">TITLE</h4></a>
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If there is a way to remove the `<br/>` tag and add it to before the link, that would be cherry on top of the cake.

This is what I have tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("document").ready(function () {
            $('.wpdm-download-link').each(function () {
                var theLink = $(this).attr('href');
                $(this).parentsUntil("div.caption h4").wrap("<a href='" + theLink + "'></div>");

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Where is the script.?

Comment: There isn't a script - I've tried several things but nothing and got frustrated so started from scratch. I tried using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224616/get-link-href-and-apply-it-to-another-link-jquery as a foundation but got nowhere fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet :

```js
$(".wpdm-pro").each(function(e,i) {
    var link = $(this).find('a');
    var title = $(this).find('h4');
    var newLink = link.html(title).clone();
    var caption = $(this).find('.caption');
    caption.children().not('br').remove();
    caption.prepend(newLink);
});
```

-- Locate link and title, add title to link and clone link. Delete anything from `.caption` except `<br>`, insert cloned link as first item to `.caption` --

produces :

```html
<div class="wpdm-pro">
    <div class="metro-block span4 wpdm-metro mm-block-03">
        <div class="caption">
           <a class="wpdm-download-link wpdm-download-locked btn btn-success" rel="noindex nofollow" href="http://123.com">
             <h4 class="media-heading" style="padding: 0px;margin:0px">TITLE</h4>
           </a>
           <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent thanks - definitely gives me something to work with if I need to amend it further. Thanks!